# Resource that has short (1-2 sentences) summaries for Perakim in Tanach?

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach

Does anyone know something that has very short summaries for each perek in tanach (to memorize)?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

At the end of artscrolls Tanach there's a short summary of each chapter, its called Tanach at a glance or something . .

Comment: I just googled (as I don't own) and the "at a glance" seems to be in multiple editions (Stone English, and Jaffe, at least), and does the parashas for chumash and perakim for the rest of Nach

Answer (score 2):

The [simanim tanach](https://www.hamadaf-y.co.il/%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%9A/%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%9A-%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C/) has a few words on each new subject brought up (not per perek, per subject), it's very clear and precise in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Awes!

**The Living Torah** (*one volume - by [Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryeh_Kaplan)*) and the continuation of this series, **The Living Nach** (*three volumes - by [Rabbi Yaakov Elman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Elman) and others*) break down Tanach not by their printed chapter numbers (*of Christian origin*), but by their original Jewish chapters called [פרשיות פתוחה and פרשיות סתומה](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parashah) and provide a **terse summary of a few words at the beginning of each section**. There's a table of contents at the beginning of each volume that indexes and paginates each of the summaries.

The following additional resources exist for The Living Torah volume:

- an [online scan](https://archive.org/details/LivingTorah_201811/Bible%20OT%20condensed/LivingTorah/) with a download link
- [another online scan](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL28377246M/The_Living_Torah) at Open Library